# function overloading with signed and unsigned r value reference

Tags: c++

I was trying to understanding r value reference in function overloading as in the code below.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void test(int && n) {
    cout << "in test int &&" << endl;
}

void test(unsigned int && n) {
    cout << "in test unsigned int &&" << endl;
}

int main() {
    unsigned int n = 5;
    test(std::move(n)); // ---> 1
    test(n);            // ---> 2
    test(5);            // ---> 3

    return 0;
}
```

Below is the output

```
in test unsigned int &&
in test int &&
in test int &&
```

output line 1 is expected and output line 3 is also expected as default int is signed. But didn't understand output line 2. When I call `test(n)`, I expected it to call `test(unsigned int && n)` as n is unsigned instead `test(int && n)` is getting called. Can any one please let me know why `test(int && n)` is getting called.

Comment: I think this is because a temporary is created and the temporary can be moved without help, so I tacked `int i = 5; test(i);` onto the end to see if the unsigned version got called. It did, but I think you want a language lawyer here to quote line and verse, something I can't do. Heck, I could be dead wrong and the test was positive for a completely different reason.

Comment: @user4581301 "*I tacked `int i = 5; test(i);` onto the end to see if the unsigned version got called. It did*" - makes sense. It is the same issue as described in Ted's answer. `test(i)` can't call `void test(int &&)` since an rvalue reference can't bind to an lvalue, but an `int` can be converted to an `unsigned int`, so `test(unsigned int &&)` gets called on a temporary rvalue that the compiler creates.

Comment: @Remy I got my confirmation a few minutes later when I remembered that `std::move` was nothing but a shortcut version of a [potentially ugly cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move#Return_value). By then Ted had answered and there wasn't enough value I could add to be worth it. Plus the build was just about done.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`test(n);` can't use `void test(unsigned int&&)`. The function would try to bind an rvalue reference to an lvalue.

The compiler then tries to find a match via conversion of `n` and finds that it can convert `n` to an `int` (which then becomes an rvalue) to get a match, hence `void test(int&&)` wins.